# Solr - Include a field only if other fields where found

Tags: search, solr, field, relevance

Assuming I have the fields

```
textFieldA
textFieldB
specialC
```

in my index. Now I want to query these with

```
textFieldA:"searchVal" textFieldB:"searchVal" specialC:"somecode"
```

But I only want to boost matches on `specialC` if there were also matches on at least one of the other fields.

#### Example:

```
DocumentA:
 textFieldA:"This is a test" textFieldB:"for clarification" specialC:"megacode"

DocumentB:
 textFieldA:"Doesnt contain" textFieldB:"searched word here" specialC:"megacode"

DocumentC:
 textFieldA:"But this again" textFieldB:"contains test" specialC:"supercode"
```

Now when searching for example with

```
textFieldA:"test" textFieldB:"test" specialC:"supercode"
```

I want the results

```
DocumentC
DocumentA
```

with document C having the highest rank, but document B being excluded.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: how does DocumentA match as the specialC is not having value 'supercode'? At the start you mentioned that specialC should match if there is atleast one match on other fields

Comment: Sorry, I'll corrected my question. I meant that just matches on the specialC field should boost the value, so matches only on specialC should not be included

Answer (score 0):

```
q=textFieldA:"test" OR textFieldB:"test" OR textFieldA:"test" AND specialC:"supercode" OR textFieldB:"test" AND specialC:"supercode"&bq=(specialC:"supercode")^100
```

Should return only DocumentC and DocumentA in the desired order. bq means boosting one field/ field value, see more here https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F .

As far as I know query boosting works only if you actually query for the thing you want to boost (kind of intuitive). That is why I added the last 2 parts to the query.